# Where do you include FirePHP in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, firebug, firephp

I'm using `require_once()` in header.php to include the FirePHP library. In the page.php I'm doing the usual...

```
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
$firephp->log($categories);
```

Getting these errors..

```
'Headers already sent....'
```

and

```
Cannot send log data to FirePHP. You must have Output Buffering enabled via ob_start() or output_buffering ini directive...
```

I figured the using require_once in the template's header.php (above all HTML output) would be safe (pre header output). Guess this is not the case.

Anyone have experience with this? (P.S. I tried the WP FirePHP plugin, wasn't working right)

Comment: Which header.php do you mean, the one in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirePHP uses the output headers to transfer debugging data to the browser. So the `require_once()` statement is not the problem, but the fact that you do logging in `page.php`, at which point HTML has already been output. Not only do you need to include FirePHP before any content has been sent - you need to also do all logging before sending content as well.

The usual workaround is to hold any output to the browser using output buffering and the `ob_*` family of functions. That enables you to send out headers even though `echo()` commands (and the likes) have already been issued.

I am guessing doing all this safely is what the WP_FirePHP plugin was made for. I would recommend taking a second look at that plugin.

Comment: Changing the output_buffering directive to On in php.ini did the trick for me. (also I was using the wp-firephp plugin for Wordpress)

Comment: apparently in the wordpress admin section it will clear the headers and / or the contents of `ob_*` and so this sometimes appears to break FirePHP

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
<?php
require_once(/FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
ob_start();
?>
```

at the top of your header file.